# Show available languages, but remove "Language Undefined"

Tags: i18n-l10n

I want to show the available languages, that works, but how can I hide the "Language: undefined" text if "language neutral" is selected.

Thx,
Andi

Comment: But where exactly you want to do that?

Comment: Where? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not answering the question directly, but you can disabled 'Language Neutral' (and other languages) on a per-content type basis using [Disable "Language neutral"](https://drupal.org/project/dnl).